# How to bind UIButton action in UITableViewCell in MVVM

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, binding, uibutton

I have the following **MVVM** architecture. It is not something special, just for better understanding.

[image]

What is the main question is:

**How do I need to bind `UIButton` action to make some reaction in `UIViewController`.**

I try to do it the following way:

1) First of all, I add the property as a closure for `ViewModel`:

```
var cellButtonActionCallback: (() -> Void)?
```

2) I add the same property for `CellViewModel`:

```
var buttonCallback: (() -> Void)?
```

3) When I setup `CellViewModel` do:

```
cellViewModel.buttonCallback = cellButtonActionCallback
```

4) And finally add target for `UIButton`, and selector **buttonAction**
calls **buttonCallback** as well:

```
button.bind { cellViewModel.buttonAction() }
```

Looks like closure which I define on `UITableViewController` goes through all `viewModels` which is not a good idea in my way.

Actually, this approach works fine, but I don't like it.

**What is the best way to make the same thing?**

Comment: From my understanding, if you can implement delegate through viewmodel it will be a suitable option.